# Unity Stuck on Application.UpdateScene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, game-engine

My game was working fine all long for days. Recently just after adding attack animation for my enemyai it started freezing everytime I clicked on play.

So when I click play unity pops up with a message saying "Hold On ! Application.UpdateScene" and its stuck on that ever since. The only way for me to exit is using task manager.

Screenshot:

[image]

I tried debbing and adding break points but it did not work. At this point I don't know what wrong is it my code or something else.

I haven't updated my unity I am on 2020.1f but I don't think that might be causing the problem.

Also incase it's not possible to resolve this problem can you'll please tell me a way to complete my project quicker without redoing it everything.

Thanks

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/application-updatescene-when-modifying-textures.944113/

Answer (score 3):

It is usually caused by a dead-loop.

I also has this issue today. I solved it by attaching the debugger (Visual Studio in my case) to the forever loading Unity Editor. After that, pause the debugger. This will freeze Unity but we can then inspect where the code is executing at this particular moment. Select the inspecting thread to "Unity Thread" in Visual Studio. In my case, it immediately show the code is running inside a while-loop which I forgot to increase the i variable and turn the loop into a dead loop.

Comment: this issue is not caused by a tight loop. This is Unity 2020.3 being Unity 2020.3

Answer (score 0):

The reason is just delete your Library package in your project folder then reopen your project unity recreate the file. The problem appears when you import assets from asset store.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).